# No GitHub, qual a diferença entre um projeto e um repositório?

Tags: github

No GitHub, vi que posso criar um um repositório, mas também posso criar um projeto. Qual a diferença entre um e outro? Quando devo criar um projeto em vez de um repositório e vice-versa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe uma confusão com o termo **projeto** na definição das duas coisas, isso porque geralmente se entende como projeto a pasta criada durante o desenvolvimento que contém os arquivos fontes.

De qualquer forma, aqui estão as definições utilizadas no GitHub:

**Repositório**

Pode ser comparado à pasta raiz do seu projeto, esteja ele na IDE ou em seu filesystem. Irá conter toda a estrutura de arquivos e documentação de seus fontes, bem como um sistema de versionamento para o mesmo.

É a estrutura mais básica do GitHub, normalmente os **Projetos** se baseiam no fluxo de atividades ocorrendo no **Repositório** para a organização das tarefas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Projeto**

Uma estrutura mais complexa que não envolve apenas a visão do código fonte, como a do repositório. Assemelha-se as ferramentas de gerenciamento e acompanhamento de projetos de software, isso envolve desde a criação de tarefas e o acompanhamento de seu andamento.

É bem interessante para manter a rastreabilidade de problemas e pull requests, bem como dividir as atividades e seguir um fluxo de trabalho dentro do GitHub. Conforme imagem abaixo, você pode ver um Kanban com as atividades

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode conferir o no glossário o termo [repositório](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/github-glossary#repository), o projeto foi introduzido depois e sua documentação se encontra [aqui](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/tracking-the-progress-of-your-work-with-project-boards).

Um detalhe interessante é que projetos podem ser derivados de **Repositórios** ou **Organizações**, por exemplo, o repositório do [spring-security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security) não possui nenhum projeto, mas a Spring possui um [projeto](https://github.com/orgs/spring-projects/projects/1) voltado para o time de segurança deles.

**Quando devo criar um ou outro?**

Caso você esteja buscando apenas versionar seus arquivos de forma simples e direta, vá de repositório.

Se dentro do seu repositório ou organização você gostaria de acompanhar o fluxo de trabalho de projetos (repositórios), bem como propor atividades e acompanhar o progresso das mesmas com seus colaboradores, crie um projeto.

Não existe regra para criação de um projeto, isso vai mesmo da necessidade do time que está trabalhando.